# Search Controller get dismiss on getting back?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Suppose, I am in discuss view controller, and there I opened searchBar controller for searching something. And then I changed the tab to Jobs view controller. and now I again get back to discuss view controller, then Search Bar controller get dismissed instead of getting visible on screen. And this is happening in the case of navigation also.

Answer (score 0):

You posted no code, so my answer will be an assumption of what could be going wrong.

When you are switching `view controllers` the `search bar` is resigning it's `active state`. One solution you should try is to set it back to `active` when the view controller `reappears`.

Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  //Set the search controller to active

  //Replace self.searchController to however you are referencing the searchController, I will assume its a property of the view controller
  self.searchController.searchBar.active = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

  //Set it to inactive
  self.searchController.searchBar.active = NO;
}
```